# Decoding attachment encoded as base64 string

Tags: c#, email, encoding, base64, mime-types

I have an email that was sent to me with an attachment, however for some reason it came through as a base64 encoded string.  Half way down the email it looks like this;

```
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed; name="me.zip";

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="me.zip"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



UEsDBBQAAQAIANeV9y5y6d5oG..... etc.
```

I have tried copying it in to an online base64 decoder (using utf-8) and then copying the resultant text in to a file and renaming as .zip, but this does not work.  Can anyone help me get this attachment?  There is no way of getting another copy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Copying the result into a text file is probably a good way of garbling the data. Whip up a short C# snippet and try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this as "c#" I reckon you are OK writing a brief code snippet, in which case you can use [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then write the resulting byte array to a file.

The linked Microsoft documentation shows an example of just what you want -- reading a file, decoding it from base 64, and then writing the result.

Comment: The reason the online doesn't work is because you are trying to decode a base64 encoded zip file to text.  If your attachment was a base64 encoding of a utf-8 text file then it would work.